# How did Smaug know to call Thorin "Thorin Oakenshield"?

Tags: the-hobbit, the-desolation-of-smaug

In the Desolation of Smaug, when Smaug was talking to Bilbo, he made a reference to Thorin as "Thorin Oakenshield". How did he know to call Thorin "Oakenshield" since he only got the name Oakenshield when he tried to reclaim Moria when Smaug took the mountain?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46612/how-does-smaug-know-the-name-oakenshield